# Problems with clean install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Error parsing PCC subspace from PCCT) on Lenovo X250

Tags: boot, lenovo

I did a full install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) on new 8gb ram, 192GB HDD Lenovo X250 (i5-5200) using a USB-stick (USB 2.0). The system is new and came with Windows 10 which I won't use so was wiped out (no dual boot).

The UEFI secure boot is "Off" though in the Startup page UEFI/Legacy Boot is set to "Both" and "Legacy First." "CSM Support" is set to yes. Boot Mode is set to Diagnostics and Boot Order Lock is disabled. Network Boot is [PCI LAN: IBA GE] I believe the only graphics card is intel based  (Intel HD Graphics 5500).

I get initramfs prompt (see below picture) and have no clues about how to proceed (consider me noob so would really appreciate explanations of any commands that may help).

[image: attached-picture]

The first two lines...

```
"[1.986000] Error parsing PCC subspace from PCCT"
"[1.986204] ACPI PCC probe failed."
```

I created bootable usb for Ubuntu (& Ubuntu-mate) from a linux machine using dd command from https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744 but even with that it shows up though I have not yet tried to reinstall it yet.

I think I have looked at potential solutions but apologies if I missed the relevant one. Any help, including pointers, would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

A clean install solved the problem. I had unmounted the usb incorrectly in the first install.